# jQuery Ajax file upload with progress hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using jQuery to upload files. Everything worked fine, until I've added `xhr: function () {...}` code to track file upload progress. Now it just hangs after `Start loading image...`. If I remove this block from `$.ajax`, file upload works.

```
function showProgress(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
    $('.meter').attr({'width': percentComplete + '%'});
  }
}


console.log('Start loading image...')
$.ajax({
  url: '/uploadimage',
  type: 'POST',
  xhr: function () {
    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    if (myXhr.upload) {
      myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', showProgress, false);
    } else {
      console.log("Upload progress is not supported.");
    }
    return myXhr;
  },

  //Ajax events
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    // CSRF...
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // do smth
  },

  // Form data
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
});
```

What I'm doing with upload progress wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this resolved? Are you using the upload templates provided or using your own custom markup?

The following works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnContinue').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadChunk", "Upload")',
        maxChunkSize: 1048576,
    }).addClass('fileupload-processing')
    .bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {
        if ($('#fileIds').val().indexOf(';' + data.result.id + ';') == -1) {
            var pre = $('#fileIds').val() == "" ?  ';' : '';
            var append = $('#fileIds').val() + pre + data.result.id + ';';
            $('#fileIds').val(append);
        }
    })
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $('#btnContinue').prop('disabled', false);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    });
});
</script>
```

I do have an issue with my setup, but you should be able to reference my code for what you are trying to achieve.

[Submit Additional Form Data without setting formData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282001/jquery-file-upload-submit-additional-form-data-without-setting-formdata)